# / to %2f convert back in Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, scala

I have seen this question before but no one is really answering them.
So my issue is that I have a ajax request that takes in value from a text field in the format of: 00000000/relay_1A
but I will get a 404 error when I try to submit. But it will work if I do 00000000%2frelay_1A. I understand that the %2f = / but I can not have my users use that format to get a correct result. So is there a way to have the text field automatically convert the / to %2f in the backend.

```
  <div id="input_controlGet" style="display:none"> 

  <div class='col-md-2'>
  <br>
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="input_ControlGetmac">
      <div class="panel-heading" id="header_ControlGetmac">
        Mac Address 
      </div>
          <input id="login_ControlGetmac" type="text" class="form-control input-normal">
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" id="input_ControlGetpoint">
      <div class="panel-heading" id="header_ControlGetpoint">
        Point Input 
      </div>
          <input id="login_ControlGetpoint" type="text" class="form-control input-normal" placeholder="Fill In">
    </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sumbit_controlGet">Submit</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
  $('#sumbit_controlGet').on 'click', ->
    username = $('#login_username').val()
    password = $('#login_password').val()
    mac_id = $('#login_ControlGetmac').val()
    point = $('#login_ControlGetpoint').val()

    $.ajax
      type: "GET"
      url: start_url + mac_id + "/control/" + point
      dataType: "json"
      crossDomain: true
      cache: false
      beforeSend: beforeSend(username, password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `decodeURIComponent()` to do this:

```
var x = "00000000%2frelay_1A";
alert(decodeURIComponent(x)); // = '00000000/relay_1A'
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bZTd/)

Or `encodeURIComponent()` to re-encode:

```
var x = "00000000/relay_1A";
alert(encodeURIComponent(x)); // = '00000000%2frelay_1A'
```

Comment: Hmm, but my users can use a varies amount of variables likes
00000000%2frelay_2A,
00000000%2frelay_3A,
etc

Comment: There is also `encodeURIComponent()`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: THANKS! But where would I do this in my ajax request, which I posted above ^

Comment: I would guess around the `mac_id` and `point` variables before you concatenate them in the URL.

Comment: how would I do this in CoffeeScript?

Comment: Sorry I've never used it. You're best to start a new question for that.

Comment: Have you double checked the URL is valid

Comment: Yep when I try 00000000%2frelay_1A, it will work but not 00000000/relay_1A.

Comment: Worked Thank You All,
      url: start_url + mac_id + "/control/" + encodeURIComponent(point)